# Partition Data compression

Tags: sql-server

We’ve an Audit Table in our DB, which holds records concerning the user Activity .
The Table is partitioned by the DATE column (Per month), and doesn’t have any binary columns . 
We are obliged due to customer specification to keep the DATA for 6 months , the DATA should be available for Querying and further  Investigations if needed.

1. Is there a way to compress old DATA ( older than 6 months ) by Partition  ?
2. are there any recommended  considerations when compressing by Partitions ?
3. what is the scenario while splitting or merging compressed Partitioned ?
4. is there any effect while deleting  a complete partition ?

Thx.

Comment: What version/edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQLServer 2012 Ent. Edition.

Comment: Have you considered using Azure SQL Database? You can use Elastic database client libraries to partition the data and Split-Merge service to split and merge the databases as and when required. You can get details information about these capabilities of Azure SQL Database here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/sql-database-elastic-scale/

Answer (score 2):

Data compression works at a partition level. So, if you're partitioning by date, you can compress "old" data as you see fit. As for when to use it, check out the BOL article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx).

As to merging/splitting partitions, BOL says that this is an offline operation, so you may incur some downtime there.

As for deleting a partition, you'd typically create a new table with the same schema, do an "alter table...switch partition" statement and then drop the new table. That *should* be just a metadata change.